# SharePoint 2010 Variations

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Our client is having sharepoint site which will open in different countries such as in Russia,Germany,China,Euro..etc. When the site is opened in china country then site should automatically open in Chinese language.In the same way,If SharePoint 2010 site is opened in Russia country then  sharepoint site should open in Russian language.This type of scenario should apply to all the countries.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to actually be asking a question here, so I'll give a couple of pointers for you to work from.

[This Microsoft blog post](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=366) gives a brief introduction to the out-of-the-box localisation available for Sharepoint 2010.

You will have to develop something (possibly part of one of your core masterpages) that will determine the users desired language (I'd suggest going with browser strings if available over the IP-address based), and set the language for the session to that.

You will need to remember to properly localise any custom features you build (web parts, content types, etc.). Again [Microsoft have a useful article giving an introduction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee696750.aspx).